# Nmap Error when using the “–script” arg

Tags: 12.04, networking, scripts, scanner, nmap

i just installed the nmap network scanner, and when i try to use it whith the "-script" parameter, it doesn't work: example:

```
soufiane@soufiane-cvc:/usr/local$ nmap -p143,993 -Pn –script imap-capabilities 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-03 10:07 WEST
Failed to resolve "–script".
Failed to resolve "imap-capabilities".
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000025s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
143/tcp closed imap
993/tcp closed imaps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
```

Comment: Did you copy-paste that command from somewhere? it looks like the ASCII double hyphen `--` got converted into a unicode en dash `–`

Answer (score 2):

Using the right syntax:

```
nmap -p143,993 -Pn --script imap-capabilities 127.0.0.1
```

---

*Why?*

You use

```
–script
```

and the correct syntax is

```
--script
```

and note the difference between your dash `–` and `-`